# how to select element by placeholder with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a trouble with input click. I can't use any class or id's because they are changing every time I open the browser.

Is that any option to select element by placeholder ?

```
<input _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-touched" matinput="" name="email" placeholder="Email" regexchecker="^([\w-]+(?:\.?\+?[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$" required="" id="mat-input-56" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true">
```

Answer (score 6):

You can select any element by property by using:

```
'[property="value"]'
```

in your case this should do the trick:

```
'[placeholder="Email"]'
```

Comment: You can add that you should use this with `document.querySelector` not sure if there is other way to select stuff in puppeteer, I'm not familiar with this, only skim through the docs.